# Show some texts in posts belonging to Specific category

Tags: posts, categories

I am trying to add some text to the end of every post belonging to a specific category. I am using the following code -

```
<div class="repair-tool">
    <?php 
    $catarray = get_the_category( $post->ID );
    foreach ($catarray as $cat) {
        $catid = $cat->term_id;
    
        if ($catid == 1234) {
          echo 'text';
        }
    
    } ?>
</div>
```

This is working successfully but  div class I am using is being shown in every post of the website instead. Please somebody help me out.

Answer (score 2):

It seems you are pointing to this div class "repair-tool". Correct?

If yes then you can modify your code like the below:

```
<?php
if( in_category( 1234, $post->ID ) ){
    echo '<div class="repair-tool">text</div>';
}
?>
```

Comment: Thank you so very much, Tiwari ji. Worked like a charm.